# Which one should be used to Partition clause or With clause?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

Below is the Tournament Table Structure with data.

```
|-------|-----------|
|  Team |  Result   |
|-------|-----------|
|   A   |   Win     |
|-------|-----------|
|   A   |   Loss    |
|-------|-----------|
|   A   |   Draw    |
|-------|-----------|
|   B   |   Win     |
|-------|-----------|
|   B   |   Win     |
|-------|-----------|
|   C   |   Loss    |
|-------|-----------|
|   C   |   Loss    |
|-------|-----------|
|   A   |   Draw    |
|-------|-----------|
|   C   |   Win     |
|-------|-----------|
```

Below is the required result,

```
|-------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|               
|  Team |  Win      |   Loss |  Draw  |  Total  |   
|-------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|
|   A   |   1       |   1    |  2     |     4   |
|-------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|
|   B   |   2       |   0    |  0     |     2   |
|-------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|
|   C   |   1       |   0    |  2     |     3   |
|-------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|
```

I have tried to get this result but it includes duplicate records also.

#### Using Partition Query :

```
select team,count(case when result='Won' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team ) as "Win",
count(case when result='Loss' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team) as "Loss",
count(case when result='Draw' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team) as "Draw"
from Tournament;
```

#### Using With Clause :

```
with t
as 
(select team,count(case when result='Won' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team ) as "Win",count(case when result='Loss' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team) as "Loss",count(case when result='Draw' then 1 else null end) over(PARTITION BY result,team) as "Draw"
from Tournament)
select distinct t.team, count(t."Win") as a,count(t."Loss") b,t."Draw" from t group by  t.team,t."Win",t."Loss",t."Draw" ;
```

Comment: I think you've confused yourself. The WITH clause (aka subquery factoring aka Common Table Expressions aka CTEs) is used to factor out subqueries, which can aid readability of your query and (depending on certain factors, like how many times your subquery is used in the overall query, etc) may make the query more performant. Analytic functions (which is what you've incorrectly called "partition query") are used when you want to return the whole data set but have the aggregated information available at row level.

Comment: What you need (and has been suggested in the answers below) is aggregate functions - these aggregate the information and collapse the rows down to one row per set, which is what your output shows you're after - you want one row per team, with how many games they won, draw, lost and played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `count() over()` ? I normally use this syntax for cumulative count , if you simply want a count, then use regular `COUNT()` with the `CASE EXPRESSION` with a `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select team,count(case when result='Won' then 1 end) as "Win",
            count(case when result='Loss' then 1 end) as "Loss",
            count(case when result='Draw' then 1 end) as "Draw",
            count(*) as total
from Tournament
GROUP BY team
```

Also, no need for `ELSE NULL` as it is the default of `CASE EXPRESSION` .

Comment: What about Total column?

Comment: The `COUNT(..) OVER ( PARTITION BY ...)`  syntax is not for a cumulative count - it only does that if you use an `ORDER BY` clause in which case it assumes the default window of `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. If you leave out the `ORDER BY` clause then it will use the entire partition.

Comment: Thank you @sagi In which type requirement Partition and With clause are used?

Comment: @MT0 you're right.. I rephrased , but either way the `OVER` shouldn't be used for regular counts.

Comment: For example if you want cumulative count. Usually combined with dates, and you want a count by a specific order **up until** the date. (The first record of the group will be 1, the second 2 and so on) @sheshadri

Answer (score 0):

An Alternate approach without using case or partition

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT trim(upper(result)) RESULT1,TEAMNAME FROM Tournament)
PIVOT(count(1) AS RESULT_COUNT FOR(RESULT1) IN ('WIN' AS WIN,'LOSS' AS LOSS,'DRAW' AS DRAW));